# Why am I getting a timeout error when I am connecting to MySQL using Jupyter Notebook in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, mysql-workbench

My code is as follows, which I am trying to run using the Jupyter Notebook. I am trying to connect
to MySQL Workbench using the following code snippet:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='qamroll-id.com', port=3306, user='cdop-write', \
                   passwd='opread', db="ROLL", connect_timeout= 100000)
```

I am getting the following error when I am executing this code snippet:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

> OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'qamroll-id.com' ([WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)")

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Can you connect from mysql-workbench?

Comment: Yes, I can connect from Workbench

Comment: OK, then information is missing, and it's unclear why it does not work.